# Invalid Syntax jose.py

Tags: python, jose

I was trying to use jose library for authentication for one of my flask apps.
using the import statement as follows

```
from jose import jwt
```

But it throws following An error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "F:/XXX_XXX/xxxx-services-web/src/auth.py", line 6, in <module>
      from jose import jwt
   File "F:\Users\XXXX_XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jose.py", line 546
      print decrypt(deserialize_compact(jwt), {'k':key},
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is this library outdated?

Comment: seems like it's written for python 2 - you should search for python3 compatible alternatives or maybe try using [2to3 library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) to automatically migrate the library's source.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

installing python-jose instead of jose fixed my problem.
https://pypi.org/project/python-jose/

Answer (score 4):

Install `python-jose` instead of installing `jose`.

You can also use `import python_jwt as jwt` instead of `from jose import jwt` and install the package  via `pip install python-jwt`